# Django View Testing: Can't pull context from client's post

Tags: python, django, testing, django-templates, backend

I'm trying to make a testing suite for my view.  All of my problems seem to stem from me not being able to access the context of my render that is returned from the view. I know the problem has something to do with DjangoTemplate backend but I have no idea what I am supposed to do to get response.context populated with the necessary variables.  This is my tests.py code:

```
class JSONHandlerTester(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.jsonTestPath = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT,'json','jsonTests')
        pass


    def testing(self):
        for test in os.listdir(self.jsonTestPath):
            testFile = os.path.join(os.path.join(self.jsonTestPath),test)
            split = test.split('.')
            testName = split[0]
            testNameArray = re.findall('[a-zA-z][^A-Z]*', testName)
            project = testNameArray[0]
            team = testNameArray[1]
            with open(testFile) as json:
                response = self.client.post('/JSONChecker', {'json_project': project, 'json_team': team, 'json': json})
            print response
            print response.context
            if (response.context['title'] == "Congratulations!!! Your JSON Passes!!!" and testNameArray[2] == "Pass") or (response.context['title'][2:] == "The" and testNameArray[2] == "Fail"):
               print test+': Works'
            else:
               print test+': BREAKS: PROBLEM DETECTED'
```

This is what the render looks like:

```
return render(request, 'JSONChecker.html',context = {'title': title, 'validationErrors':validationErrors,'errors':errors, 'isLoggedIn':isLoggedIn, 'form': form, 'post':post})
```

EDIT: When I run the test, I get `TypeError: NonType object has no attribute.` It is on the line of my if statement. I printed out my `response.context` and found that it printed out `None`. This is how I know that the problem comes from me not being able to pull the context variables from that dict in the render.

I'm using `Django 1.11` with `Python 2.7`

Comment: What happens when you run the test?

Comment: @Alasdair I get a 'NonType' object has no attribute __getitem__ error. I printed out response.context and it printed out None. I know the error stems from me not being able to pull the context from the self.client.post but I have no idea how to solve that.

Comment: Check `response.status_code` and `response.content`. They might give you a clue what’s going on.

Comment: @Alasdair Interesting, I'm getting a 301 error on my status_code and content doesn't print anything out.  If I run my code normally everything works just fine and I get what I would expect from my view. Is it because I end up overwriting the same page dynamically? Is that bugging out the Django Testing system?

Comment: A 301 is a permanent redirect. No, it’s probably not a bug in the Django testing system. It’s more likely to be something in your urls or views that is causing the redirect.

Comment: @Alasdair How would I go about debugging this? My project works when I'm serving my site and just inputting in files manually. That's whats puzzling me. I'm trying to understand the difference between the two. I'm clearly not doing something right in my tests.py if that's the only thing in my project having a problem.